# Use BIND for RFC 1918 addresses

Tags: bind

I have multiple BIND servers, some are resolvers and some are authorative DNS servers.

When querying the resolvers for reverse pointer records for 10.x.x.x IPs the query fails. I have added these reverse pointer records on the auth DNS servers. Now, as I understand it, I need to tell my BIND resolvers to ask my BIND DNS servers for records relating to this IP range (otherwise they will query the root servers and fail).

How can I configure this?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure [**forward zones**](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch10_05.htm#dns4-CHP-10-SECT-5.2) on your resolvers and point them to your authoritative servers. The configuration may look along the lines of the following example:

```
// forward queries for 10.0.0.0/24 to the name servers at
// 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2
zone "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa" in {
  type forward;
  forwarders { 192.168.1.1; 192.168.1.2; };
};
```